# How to create a capped collection in a domain object in Grails using GORM / MongoDB plugin

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

I wonder if it is possible to link a capped collection to a domain object like for example:

class DomainObject {

```
 static mapping = {
    createdOn capped: true, max: 1, size: 10000
```

}

I did not find a way to do it from the domain object.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this to work so instead I manually created a capped colletion in mongo and used it in grails. It seems to work great.